# The \pbox makes the text crowded

Tags: tables, line-spacing

The result is as follows: you will see it is too crowded.
And the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}
% For multiletter symbols
\newcommand\Rey{\mbox{\textit{Re}}}  % Reynolds number
\newcommand\Str{\mbox{\textit{St}}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l}\hline
    \hline
    \pbox{55cm}{$\Rey=68$ \\$\Str=0.12$ }\\
    \pbox{55cm}{$\Rey=84$ \\$\Str=0.13$}\\
    \pbox{55cm}{$\Rey=103$\\$\Str=0.14$}\\
    \pbox{55cm}{$\Rey=119$\\$\Str=0.15$}\\
    \pbox{55cm}{$\Rey=134$\\$\Str=0.16$}\\
    \pbox{55cm}{$\Rey=171$\\$\Str=0.17$}\\\hline
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please write a minimalistic [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @strpeter .I read the page you give and Yes, I know I give some worthless package in the MWE which is useful in the whole thesis. I will correct in the next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `\pbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec,tabularx,amsmath}

% For multiletter symbols
\DeclareMathOperator\Real{Re} % cf plain TeX's \Re and Reynolds number
\DeclareMathOperator\imag{Im} % cf plain TeX's \Im
\newcommand{\constant}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand\Rey{\constant{Re}}  % Reynolds number
\newcommand\Pran{\constant{Pr}} % Prandtl number, cf TeX's \Pr product
\newcommand\Pen{\constant{Pe}}  % Peclet number
\newcommand\Str{\constant{St}}

\newcommand{\splitbox}[1]{%
  \linespread{1}\selectfont
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}

\linespread{1.3}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}


\mainmatter
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXXXXXX}\hline
     &1d&&3d&&6d&\\
     &MSP&SLP&MSP&SLP&MSP&SLP\\\hline
    \splitbox{$\Rey=68$ \\$\Str=0.12$}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \splitbox{$\Rey=84$ \\$\Str=0.13$}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \splitbox{$\Rey=103$\\$\Str=0.14$}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \splitbox{$\Rey=119$\\$\Str=0.15$}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \splitbox{$\Rey=134$\\$\Str=0.16$}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \splitbox{$\Rey=171$\\$\Str=0.17$}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\caption{sss}
\label{tab2:2}
\end{table}
\backmatter

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Notes

I have removed the packages not necessary for the example and modified the definitions of your constants in a better way: this will ensure that italics is used in any situation.

Avoid tampering with parameters such as `\hoffset` and `\voffset`: for changing the page parameters it's much easier using `geometry`.

Don't load `xunicode` (it's not necessary); also `xltxtra` shouldn't be necessary: some of its features could also give problems, so load it *only* if you need those extra features (usually you don't).

Comment: @egreg: Can you explain, why `\pbox` should be omitted? Is it tabu or why are other commands like `\splitbox` in this case better?

Comment: @strpeter I don't know too much about `pbox`; what I saw in the example tells me it has several flaws.

Answer (score 2):

tabularx affects the setting of multiline cells, and the only column for which you had more than one line you were not using `X`. Also I removed some packages to make your example more minimal (they generate missing font errors as posted for me)

[image]

This just used X and removes pbox:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%   (UTF-8/XeLaTex)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{book}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}


% For multiletter symbols
\newcommand\Real{\mbox{Re}} % cf plain TeX's \Re and Reynolds number
\newcommand\imag{\mbox{Im}} % cf plain TeX's \Im
\newcommand\Rey{\mbox{\textit{Re}}}  % Reynolds number
\newcommand\Pran{\mbox{\textit{Pr}}} % Prandtl number, cf TeX's \Pr product
\newcommand\Pen{\mbox{\textit{Pe}}}  % Peclet number
\newcommand\Str{\mbox{\textit{St}}}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0.46cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}


\setlength{\voffset}{0.46cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.7cm}

\linespread{1.3}
\pagestyle{plain}



\begin{document}


\mainmatter
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}XXXXXXX}\hline
     &1d&&3d&&6d&\\
     &MSP&SLP&MSP&SLP&MSP&SLP\\\hline
    $\Rey=68$ \\$\Str=0.12$ & $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    $\Rey=84$ \\ $\Str=0.13$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    $\Rey=103$\\$\Str=0.14$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    $\Rey=119$\\$\Str=0.15$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    $\Rey=134$\\$\Str=0.16$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    $\Rey=171$\\$\Str=0.17$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$&$6 \sim 86$\\\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\caption{sss}
\label{tab2:2}
\end{table}
\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works,thanks, and it is easy to read and I can only copy the code to the corresponding place. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

REVISED SOLUTION to eliminate use of `\pbox`.  Here, I replaced your use of the `\pbox` with a `\stackanchor`, with extra vertical separation provided by way of `\addstackgap`.  I wrapped it all up in a newly defined macro `\mystack{}{}`.  In that definition, the `[3pt]` and `[6pt]` vertical gap specifiers may be changed to suit.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}
% For multiletter symbols
\newcommand\Rey{\mbox{\textit{Re}}}  % Reynolds number
\newcommand\Str{\mbox{\textit{St}}}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\mystack[2]{\ensurestackMath{%
  \def\stackalignment{l}\addstackgap[3pt]{\stackanchor[6pt]{#1}{#2}}}}
\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXXXXXX}\hline
     &1d&&3d&&6d&\\
     &MSP&SLP&MSP&SLP&MSP&SLP\\\hline
    \mystack{\Rey=68}{\Str=0.12}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \mystack{\Rey=84}{\Str=0.13}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \mystack{\Rey=103}{\Str=0.14}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \mystack{\Rey=119}{\Str=0.15}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \mystack{\Rey=134}{\Str=0.16}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$\\
    \mystack{\Rey=171}{\Str=0.17}& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$& $6 \sim 86$&$6 \sim 86$\\\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\caption{sss}
\label{tab2:2}
\end{table}
\backmatter

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the vertical gap specifiers to, for example,

```
\newcommand\mystack[2]{\ensurestackMath{%
  \def\stackalignment{l}\addstackgap[6pt]{\stackanchor[4pt]{#1}{#2}}}}
```

gives a visually altered result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, A good example that I can adjust the height. For me, I have no the \usepackage{stackengine}.And I use the MikTex Package Manager to install and find it OK.

Comment: @ytyyutianyun As you mention, the package can be found at http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.  If your installation of MikTeX can't auto-install it, you can always place the .sty file in your working directory until you find out how to install it.